# Make background image in beamer fill full page while preserving aspect ratio

Tags: beamer, graphics

I want to use a picture as a full-page background of a particular beamer slide.
I want the picture to fill the whole slide, but preserve its aspect ratio (which is different from that of the slide), in a manner that the picture gets centred (horizontally and vertically) on the slide and scaled up exactly to the point where the picture covers the whole slide (so the visible part gets cropped along the relatively longer side of the picture).

In other words, I want to replicate the "Fill Screen" behaviour commonly found for desktop backgrounds (such as in OS X).

What is a clean way to achieve the desired behaviour in beamer?

---

The following minimal working example 
covers the background, but does not scale proportionally (first slide), or
scales the picture proportionally, but neither centres it, nor covers the whole background (second slide):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

{\usebackgroundtemplate{%
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{test.jpg}}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}}

{\usebackgroundtemplate{%
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{test.jpg}}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}}

\end{document}
```

Slide 1:
[image: Slide 1]

Slide 2:
[image]

[Link to test picture used](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:PM5644.jpg)

Comment: You only need to give one of the options `width,height`. Otherwise it is not preserving the aspect ratio. Whichever is smaller let it to page heught or width and it should be done.

Comment: @percusse, it appears to me that this does not center the image; also, I would prefer a solution for which I do not have to hard-code which of the two dimensions to match.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: tigers]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

{\usebackgroundtemplate{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
      \node at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=.1\paperwidth,height=.1\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{tiger}};%
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}}
{\usebackgroundtemplate{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
      \node at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{tiger}};%
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}}

\end{document}
```

[image: cropped wildlife]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newlength{\picwidth}

\begin{document}

{\usebackgroundtemplate{%
    \settowidth{\picwidth}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{tiger}}%
    \ifdim\picwidth<\paperwidth
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
      \node at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{tiger}};%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \else
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
      \node at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{tiger}};%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \fi
  }
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

[`adjustbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) package has a `min size` option which saves some typing:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz,adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\usebackgroundtemplate{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]% 
         \node[at=(current page.center)]{%
         \adjustbox{min size={\paperwidth}{\paperheight}}%
                   {\includegraphics{PM5644.jpg}}};}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It appears to me that this solution, while very elegant, may lead to parts of the picture being cropped even along the relatively shorter dimension if the picture is larger than the slide; while this is a possible interpretation of my original question, I prefer the picture to be scaled (up or down) to exactly the point where it covers the whole slide.

I think this modification of your code may yield this behaviour:

`\adjustbox{min size={\paperwidth}{\paperheight}}                {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{test.jpg}}`